# Java Allure Report - Playwright | how to take screenshot on test failure

Tags: java, allure, playwright-java

Selenium : Take screenshot method:

```
 " if (scenario.isFailed()) {
String screenshotName = scenario.getName().replaceAll(” “, “_”);
try {
TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
File sourcePath = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
File destinationPath = new File(
System.getProperty(“user.dir”) + “\\target\\cucumber-reports\\screenshots\\” + screenshotName + “.png”); "
```

Takes screenshot method is available is selenium, we need a solution for java+playwright
or if allure-selenide also helps.

Comment: I think https://playwright.dev/java/docs/screenshots this can help you. and the method mentioned in question is with cucumber. You can try playwright with cucumber.

Comment: Yeah we can use this but saved screenshots are not coming in the allure report